# Make load-library's TAB completion to ignore backup files

Tags: completion, load

Is it possible to make `load-library`'s TAB completion to ignore backup files (`.el~`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `load-library` is just a few lines long.  If we type `M-x find-function RET load-library RET` we see that the variable `completion-ignored-extensions` is let-bound to `nil`.  Therefore, a new function would be needed that either sets `completion-ignored-extensions` on a let-bound basis to the desired value(s) or eliminates the variable entirely from the function so its default values will shine through.  Instead of creating a function with a new name such as `load-library-one` or `load-library-two`, it is possible to use the same name (i.e., `load-library`) to replace the prior function with the newly defined function.  Or, use `defalias` if so desired.

For more information on the variable `completion-ignored-extensions`, type `M-x describe-variable` or `C-h v`.

Permit the default value of `completion-ignored-extensions` to shine through:

```lisp
(defun load-library-one (library)
  "Load the Emacs Lisp library named LIBRARY.
LIBRARY should be a string.
This is an interface to the function `load'.  LIBRARY is searched
for in `load-path', both with and without `load-suffixes' (as
well as `load-file-rep-suffixes').

See Info node `(emacs)Lisp Libraries' for more details.
See `load-file' for a different interface to `load'."
  (interactive
     (list (completing-read "Load library: "
                            (apply-partially 'locate-file-completion-table
                                             load-path
                                             (get-load-suffixes)))))
  (load library))
```

Let-bind the value of `completion-ignored-extensions` to something specific:

```lisp
(defun load-library-two (library)
  "Load the Emacs Lisp library named LIBRARY.
LIBRARY should be a string.
This is an interface to the function `load'.  LIBRARY is searched
for in `load-path', both with and without `load-suffixes' (as
well as `load-file-rep-suffixes').

See Info node `(emacs)Lisp Libraries' for more details.
See `load-file' for a different interface to `load'."
  (interactive
   (let ((completion-ignored-extensions '(".o" "~")))
     (list (completing-read "Load library: "
                            (apply-partially 'locate-file-completion-table
                                             load-path
                                             (get-load-suffixes))))))
  (load library))
```

Comment: The default value of `completion-ignored-extensions` includes `".elc"`, so both of your examples will ignore compiled libraries. This is probably not what you want to do for `load-library`, and I expect that may be why the original function ignored `completion-ignored-extensions` in the first place.

Comment: @Tyler -- It was just an arbitrary list (based on the default value) that I shortened for purposes of creating a short example so the O.P. can see how to customize the variable on a let-bound basis.  I have now shortened the list some more and removed the ".elc".

Comment: Understood! I was half-way through a similar answer when I realized this, and gave it up as being too involved to deal with properly in the time available. I suspect this is a bug